# Is there an extension for macOS Photos for perspective correction?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, photos.app

I was wondering whether anyone knows of, or can recommend, an extension for Photos on macOS that allows correcting perspective?

Comment: Which perspective control is needed? Lens correction, keystone or more advanced combinations like the SKRWT app does on iOS - http://moblivious.com/reviews/skrwt/

Comment: Keystone correction is what I had in mind. If you know of any macOS apps besides the two in my answer, I'd love to hear about them.

Comment: I've always done this type of thing in Photoshop but +1 for doing the research & providing a good working/starter answer for Photos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [app “Perspective Photos Extension”](https://itunes.apple.com/app/perspective-photos-extension/id1073437925) would seem to be the answer to my question. But neither its screenshots nor its reviews convinced me it would be worth the purchase. I haven’t come across any similar app that provides a Photos extension. Instead, I decided to try [“DxO Perspective”](https://itunes.apple.com/app/dxo-perspective/id715455365) in combination with [“External Editors For Photos”](https://itunes.apple.com/app/external-editors-for-photos/id1074021862).

Answer (score 1):

I find Readdle's [Scanner Pro](https://readdle.com/scannerpro) (for iOS) does a great job of auto-detecting document edges and applying perspective correction of pages with its (automatic) Distortion Correction feature.  It can interoperate with existing images stored in the Photos app from the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but still without a satisfactory solution within the Mac Photos app.

One workaround is using the Acorn editor, an excellent, lower-cost Mac photo editor (compared to Photoshop) with most of the functionality I needed.

To fix warped photos in Acorn, first zoom out, so your image has plenty of room around the edges.  You'll need that room to drag your skew lines outside the photo's boundaries.  Then go to **Layer** > **Rotate and Transform** > **Perspective Transform**.  (Source: [Transforming Layers | Acorn 7](https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/docs/resizing__rotating__transforming____aligning_layers.html))  Adjust the image as needed.

I've attached an example of correcting a slightly skewed photo of a piece of paper.  This particular photo is not severely crooked, but you can at least get an idea of the technique.

[image: Original Photo]

[image: Navigate to Perspective Transform]

[image: De-skewing the photo by dragging the corners outward]

[image: Final Result]